# How to add ID tag globally to the whole css file?

Tags: html, css

I have footer.html for footer of the page and the corresponding css is footer_style.css file with 6000 lines of code. There are some elements (say 'p' tag or 'a href' tag ) which are given style in the footer_style.css file like p {color : red}.

I have another file which is for the body part of the page with 'p' tag & 'a href' tag elements too.

The problem is when the page loads, the css properties for the footer are imported by the body part elements because of the styles applied in footer_style.css file.

What i see as a solution is to add a <\div id="footer_wrapper"> to the footer.html and change the css like #footer_wrapper p {} and #footer_wrapper a {} so on.

But there are 1000s of tags. The css file is 6000 lines huge.

Any other solution people ?

Comment: That's one hell of a footer you must have :p

Comment: you provided the solution on your own :)

Comment: Have you tried search and replace?

Comment: @NiranjanKumar lol yeah but thats dumb one

Comment: @JeroenBellemans yes sir it is a huge one

Comment: @aris i dont think that'll work

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/).

Paste whole css file, then on top add `#footer_wrapper` and on bottom add `}`

[image]

Comment: That's a nice little tool.

Comment: you kidding me ? This ones awesome bro, thnx a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LESS. You can import css file inside less file.

Create file footer-style.less and write:

```
#footer-wrapper { /*all styles from footer_style will apply to html inside div with id footer-wrapper */
    @import "footer_style.css";
}
```

You will need to include less pipeline to your project with some task builder (like grunt).

Comment: well i am using a less pipeline already, this seems like one legit way..tnx :)

Comment: You can accept this answer if feel like it resolves your problem.